# Android throwing exception, e.getMessage() is null

Tags: android, exception

I'm currently writing an application for Android which uses Push notifications. My app is successfully registering with Google servers and getting an ID, and I have server side code which uses this ID and pushes a notification to the App, which is received.

When the push is received, I'm calling a custom class which, inside a thread, queries a remote server for information that will then be handled in the App.

The method that is called is this:

```
private Thread checkUpdate = new Thread() {
    public void run() {
        try {
            URL updateURL = new URL("http://this.site.com/some/path");
            URLConnection conn = updateURL.openConnection();

            InputStream is = conn.getInputStream();
            BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(is);
            ByteArrayBuffer baf = new ByteArrayBuffer(50);

            int current = 0;
            while ((current = bis.read()) != -1) {
                baf.append((byte) current);
            }

            /* Convert the Bytes read to a String. */
            html = new String(baf.toByteArray());
            mHandler.post(showUpdate);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            // Show message if there was an error with the site.
            Log.e("C2DM", "Exception: " + e.getMessage());

        }

    }
};
```

The line in LogCat is as follows:
07-31 18:15:59.903: INFO/C2DM(681): Exception: null

In LogCat there is no stack trace thrown because the error is handled I guess, but I'm not sure exactly what is throwing the exception or even what type of exception it is.. (though I know it's not IOException, I have tried catching that specifically and it skipped it)

Comment: Looks like exception was created without message. Try `e.printStackTrace();`

Comment: Also step through your code and put a watch on **e**, it should give you more.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Using e.printStackTrace() helped me find I was getting a NullPointerException, because I had failed to setup the object correctly.